# How can I get the name of a role with the role's ID in Discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

So, I am making a command that allows the users in my server to create aesthetic-only roles, and I already have a command to create them (they can only specify the colour and the name) and to add/remove them. However, I still want to add a feature, which searches all roles in the server if a role with the same name already exists when it is created. I found this code from another question to list all the roles in the server (and I honestly do not understand a bit what is happening in that line but it works):

```
rolelist = (", ".join([str(r.id) for r in ctx.guild.roles]))
```

This code unfortunately only returns the IDs of the roles and I can not find a way to convert the IDs into the names of the roles so that I can actually use it to check if the role created already exist. I tried adding ".name" to the end of "ctx.guild.roles" but that did not work and returned this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'
```

To summarize, I need a way to put in a string of integers taken from the previously mentioned "rolelist" variable and turn them into the names of the roles. Any help is greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils.get#discord.utils.get) function. It returns `None` if an object with specified attributes not found.

See an example below:

```py
@bot.command()
async def check_role(ctx, *, name: str):
    await ctx.send("Role with specified name found." if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=name) is None else "Role with specified name not found.")
```

If you know role ID you can do something like this:

```py
role_id = 12345
role = guild.get_role(role_id)  # get the role
print(role.name)  # print role name
```